# Запретить заменять файлы при деплое в RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Подскажите пожалуйста как на Ruby on Rails при деплое запретить заменять все файлы внутри папки public?
Я так понял как-то можно сделать через capistrano. Вопрос в том, как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Capistrano есть пункт `set: :shared_children`.

Вставьте туда необходимые папки, которые будут храниться в разделе *shared* и линковаться в *current*.

Пример:

```
set :shared_children, %w(public/uploads public/images public/system log tmp/pids tmp/sockets)
```

Answer (score 1):

А обязательно использовать capistrano?

Если не обязательно, то можно написать свой deploy task для rake.

```
task :upload do
    system("rsync --recursive --compress --links --verbose --progress --times --executability --stats --delete --exclude=public #{Rails.root}/ user@server.com:apps/my_application")
end
```

Ключевым является параметр `--exclude=public`. Если надо что-то ещё исключить из закачки на сервер, то можно добавить ещё `--exclude=public --exclude=log --exclude=tmp --exclude=.git --exclude=.env --exclude=lib/test* --exclude=*.sublime-*`